# Como selecionar o option do valor retornado com jQuery?

Tags: select, each, option

Esta variável **dados.uf** me retorna a sigla dos estados. Ex...: **SC**

Como eu faço um loop com **jQuery** para selecionar o **data-sigla** correpondente a variável **dados.uf**?

```
<select id="billing:region_id" name="billing[region_id]">
   <option value="">Por favor, selecione o estado</option>
   <option data-sigla="AC" value="485">Acre</option>
   <option data-sigla="AL" value="486">Alagoas</option>
   ...
   <option data-sigla="CE" value="490">Ceará</option>
   <option data-sigla="DF" value="511">Distrito Federal</option>
   <option data-sigla="ES" value="491">Espírito Santo</option>
```

Comment: Vi agora que editaste a pergunta e tiraste jQuery da pergunta, juntei mais à resposta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes fazer assim:

```
$('select option').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('selected', this.dataset.sigla == dados.uf);
});
```

Desse modo comparas o `dataset.sigla` de cada `option` e se o valor fôr o mesmo que `dados.uf` ele dá `true` ao atributo selected.

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ucbn55ot/

---

Vi agora que editaste a pergunta e tiraste `jQuery` da pergunta... então com JavaScript nativo podes fazer assim:

```
var dados = {
    uf: 'DF'
};
var options = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('option'));


function select(str) {
    options.forEach(function(option) {
        if (option.dataset.sigla == str) option.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
        else option.removeAttribute('selected');
    });
}

select(dados.uf);
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ucbn55ot/1/